# Why is the hash map get returning nil after passing through the hash map as a function argument?

Tags: clojure, hashmap

I am very new to clojure so this may have a simple fix. I have two examples of code that I can't seem to find the difference in why one works and the other doesn't. The first is:

```
(defn example []
  (def demokeys (hash-map "z" 1 "b" 2 "a" 3))
  (println demokeys)
  (println (get demokeys "b")))
(example)
```

which is from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/clojure/clojure_maps_get.htm. This works the way I expect it to, with it printing the hash map and then a 2 on the next line.
The second example is:

```
(defn bill-total [bill]
  (println bill) 
  (println (get bill "b"))
  (println "sometext")
  )


(bill-total[(hash-map "z" 1 "b" 2 "a" 3)])
```

which prints the hashmap, then nil, then sometext. Why does it not correctly print the 2 as it does in the previous example?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, don't use `def` within `defn` unless you need dynamic runtime declarations (and even then, you should probably reconsider). Instead, use `let` for local bindings.

As to your main question, you have wrapped the map in a vector, with those `[]` here: `(bill-total [...])`. When calling a function, you don't need to repeat its arguments vector's brackets - call it just like you call `println` or `hash-map`, because they're also just regular functions.

So in the end, it should be `(bill-total (hash-map "z" 1 "b" 2 "a" 3))`.

As a final note, there's rarely a need to explicitly use `hash-map`, especially when you already know the keys and values. So, instead of `(hash-map ...)` you can use the map literal and write `{...}`, just like in `{"z" 1, "b" 2, "a" 3}` (I used commas here just for readability since Clojure ignores them).

Comment: Awesome, thank you. My follow up question would be related to my previous mistake actually. My next step was going to be to pass in a vector of hash maps, how would I go about accessing a map element within a vector?

Comment: @bag24 If you know the vector, you can use `get-in` to walk a path over mixed vector/map data.

Comment: In your case (get-in bill ["b"]) would return 2